# What is the most goals conceded by previous year champions in new season 1st game in top 5 European league?

Tags: football, trivia, records

[Chelsea have conceded 3 goals against Burnley](https://www.premierleague.com/match/22344) in new season first game of English Premier League 2017/18 being champion of previous year.

Is this the most for a previous year champion in top 5 European league, if it isn't which team has conceded more than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, at least it's not the only one.

The analysis of all debut games in the new season of top 5 European league reigning winners from *season 1998/2000 till now*, shows that the only game that matches the same criteria was 2002/2003 Ligue 1 debut game **Guingamp vs Lyon (3:3)**, the Lyonnaise side being the reigning champions of 2001/2002 season and conceding 3 goals in the debut match of the following season.

An interesting side fact is that this milestone has been achieved thanks to the future Chelsea FC's legend but then young [Didier Drogba's late equalizer](https://youtu.be/fxSfO33ekWE?t=15s).

Comment: I'll improve my answer if I'll find an efficient way of analyzing the earlier seasons.